# Doxygen: \xrefitem command does not work as expected

Tags: doxygen

I tried to use the \xrefitem command as shown in the [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem)

My Test.h file:

```
/** @page my_errors My Errors
 *  @brief Errors page
 *
 *  Errors page contents.
 */

/** @error ERROR 101: in case a file can not be opened.
    Check about file system read/write access.*/
#define MY_ERR_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE 101

/** \error ERROR 102: in case a file can not be closed.
    Check about file system read/write access. */
#define MY_ERR_CANNOT_CLOSE_FILE 102
```

and used the ALIAS:

> ALIASES += "error=\xrefitem my_errors \"\" \"\""

The Page `My Errors` gets created, but the documentation of the two errors does not show up in the output. Do I have to add some settings?

All other preferences are default. Doxygen version is 1.8.16

Answer (score 1):

When using the comment `/// \file` at the top of the page the "errors" are displayed.
Though I get a warning:

```
my_errors:1: warning: multiple use of page label 'my_errors', (other occurrence: .../aa.h, line: 4)
```

which is not nice but doesn't disrupt the output.

Edit: I've just pushed a proposed patch regarding the warning, to github (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7260)

Comment: Ok now define 1 works. but the socond one still is not diplaye. And I get the error: test.h:16: warning: documentation for unknown define MY_ERR_CANNOT_CLOSE_FILE found.

Comment: When I use 1.8.16 and place the `/// \file` at the top of the Test.h I see both defines, their documentation with the define and on the my_errors page. Did I overlook something?